# Два действия при нажатии на кнопку jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

Вечно у меня с этим проблема... Вот код:

```
$(".phb").bind('click', function () {
    $(".fix_phb").slideDown(200);
    $(".fixfeed").addClass('active');
    return false;
});
$("#fix_close").bind('click', function () {
    $(".fix_phb").slideUp(200);
    $(".fixfeed").removeClass('active');
    return false;
});
```

Нужно снести вторую часть и работать с первой. При нажатии на .phb открываем блок и добавляем класс. При повторному сносим класс и прячем. Вроде сделал так:

```
$(".phb").bind('click', function () {
    $(".fix_phb").toggle(200);
    $(".fixfeed").toggleClass('active');
    return false;
});
```

Но вот toggle выполняет не совсем ту анимацию. Нужно оставить прижнюю slideUp/Down

Answer (score 3, accepted):

О, я снова сам разобрался. Я был близок. `.sldeToggle` мне в помощь:)